# Restore a backup if Crashplan disappears

Tags: backup, restore, crashplan

I am thinking about using [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/) as a backup solution. I am planning on making incremental backups of my computer (Daily, Monthly, Yearly). The archive file that Crashplan uses for incremental backups is a proprietary format.

My question is:

- **How would I restore** from a Crashplan proprietary archive if Crashplan goes out of business?

Comment: Have you asked Crashplan?

Comment: @alroc asked 6 days ago, waiting on response.

Comment: @techie007 Different question, They are asking about remote backups while I am asking about restoring incremental backups in their proprietary format.

Comment: Note that CrashPlan does not do the kind of incremental backups you talk about because it doesn't need to. It is a much better solution overall than traditional backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/240876/23133) from a Crashplan employee answering "[Will crashplan offsite backup work if crashplan goes out of business?](https://superuser.com/questions/240303/will-crashplan-offsite-backup-work-if-crashplan-goes-out-of-business)":

> Restore functions without our infrastructure - provided you have access to backup set. (I.e. local backup, or another computer) So no risk there.

Also see their FAQ:

- [Can I restore without an Internet connection?](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/faq/restore#can_i_restore_without_an_internet_connection)

> Local Restore (your computers) and Guest Restore (friend computers) allow you to restore directly to the computer with your backup archives

How-To's:

- [Local Restore](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/local_restore)

And Step-By-Step's:

- [How It Works - Restoring Files at Your Desktop](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/restore_files#how_it_works_-_restoring_files_at_your_desktop)

> 3) From the Backup destination list, choose the destination from which you want to restore. 
>    If you have a subscription to CrashPlan Central, it will be listed in the Backup destination list.

Comment: Yes it works, BUT HOW!?

Comment: Added some links to their site's instructions.